# Is it normal for a site size to fluctuate?

Tags: performance, shopify, pingdom

I'm curious about something I've noticed while tracking the site speed of a Shopify site in Pingdom.

The site has been unchanged for a few days, but the site of the size goes up and down by very small amounts. The number of requests also goes up and down by small amounts. Is it likely that Pingdom is just slightly off occasionally?

The times below are recorded every 30min.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure your shop uses some Javascript to provide some external services to support it. That is likely the source of "variance" in page size. Some services are dynamic in what they return as a payload, so you'd see that for page size assuming it includes all attached behaviours. As for variances in requests, that would probably be the fact that the faster a response, the more pings can be sent and processed, so slower responses should see less requests. Kind of makes sense right?